# Related Rates Question involving helium balloon

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A convertible is travelling along a straight highway at $30$ m/s, when a child in the backseat releases a helium balloon. If the balloon rises vertically at a rate of $10$ m/s, how fast is the distance between the child and the balloon increasing 1 second after the balloon is released?

Okay, so I'm trying to solve this related rates question and Im not sure if I'm going about it the right way.

I made a right triangle diagram and derived the equation and then plugged in the following values: $x=10, 
y=30$ (because we're trying to solve for one second after he releases the balloon), 
and then using Pythagorean Theorem, I solved for $z$ and got 10$\sqrt{10}$
. 
Then I plugged the values into my equation $$2x \frac{\mathrm{dx} }{\mathrm{d} t} +2y \frac{\mathrm{dy} }{\mathrm{d} t}=2z \frac{\mathrm{dz} }{\mathrm{d} t}$$ to solve for $\frac{\mathrm{dz} }{\mathrm{d} t}$, and got $\frac{38}{\sqrt{10}}$. This doesn't look quite right. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: To solve this problem it seems we need to assume something about whether the convertible's top was down. Are we sure this problem statement was written by a mathematician? :-)

Comment: This was on a practice Final, written by my professor. Hopefully he's a mathematician if he's teaching a Calculus Course in University :P

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend mentioning the "top down" thing to _him_ unless you're sure he has a great sense of humor.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply Pythagorean Theorem,

$$z = \sqrt{10^2+30^2}=\sqrt{1000} \color{blue}{{\neq 100}}$$

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

$x(t) = 30 t \ m\\
y(t) = 10 t \ m$

I felt the need to transpose your axes to put the balloon on the vertical.

$d(t) = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \ m$

$d'(t) =  \frac {1}{2\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}} (2x x' + 2y y') \ \frac {m}{s}$

Now we need $d'(1)$

$x(1) = 30\\
y(1) = 10\\
x'(1) = 30 \\
y'(1) = 10\\
d'(1) =  \frac {1}{\sqrt {900 + 100}} (10^2 + 30^2)\\
\frac {1000}{\sqrt {1000}}\\
10 \sqrt {10} \frac {m}{s}$

Actually in this case, working from:

$d'(t) =  $$\frac {1}{2\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}} (2x x' + 2y y') \\
\frac {(10 t)(10) + (30 t)(30)}{\sqrt {(30 t)^2 + (10t)^2}}  \\
\frac{1000t }{t\sqrt {1000}}\\
10\sqrt {10}\ \frac {m}{s}$

The rate of change is constant.

Comment: Okay, so you first rearranged the equation to solve for d'(t), and then took the derivative of it and plugged in the values?

Comment: I found an equation for $d$ and took the derivative to find d' (using the chain rule in this case), and then plugged the time $t$  However, there is more than one way to tackle this problem.  You could have subitutied x,y right at the start $d(t) = \sqrt { (30t)^2+ (10t)^2} = t\sqrt {1000}$ before differentiating.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!